# How do I use the across function across all columns of a dataframe rather than specify certain columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, rowsum

I have the following script so far that successfully creates a new column in my dataframe and populates it with a sum of how many times the value "TRUE" appears for each row of the dataframe:

```
data_1 <- data_1 %>% mutate(True_Count = rowSums(across(-c(Community.name), `%in%`, TRUE)))
```

You will notice after I bring in the `across` function, I specify that I want to drop a column from the function. However, I actually don't want to drop any columns from my function. I tried writing something like

`across(data_1 %in%, TRUE)` to indicate I want to go across the whole dataframe/all columns, but this is not the correct syntax.

Also, I tried to do this a much simpler way using just `rowSums` and no `mutate` as follows:

`data_1$True_Count <- rowSums(df == TRUE)` but all this did was create an empty column called `True_Count` and did not count the occurrences of `TRUE` logical values in each row. I also tried the same thing using a random string value that I know occurs exactly one time in my dataset:  `data_1$True_Count <- rowSums(df == "banana")` but this did the same thing -- it created an empty column and did not count the instance of `banana` in my dataset.

Lastly there was one more behavior that I did not understand. If I run the first code, `` data_1 <- data_1 %>% mutate(True_Count = rowSums(across(-c(Community.name), `%in%`, TRUE))) `` more than once, the counts in the `True_Count` column cease to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is really helpful if you share data in a reproducible format with the expected output so that everyone is on the same page regarding understanding of the question.

Since you did not share an example, I created one myself to explain the answer here. I have added 4 random columns with `TRUE`/`FALSE` values since it seems this is what your dataset contains.

```
data_1 <- data.frame(Community.name = c(T, F, T, F, F), 
                     Community.code = c(T, F, F, T, T), 
                     col1 = T, 
                     col2 = c(F, F, T, F, F))
data_1

#  Community.name Community.code col1  col2
#1           TRUE           TRUE TRUE FALSE
#2          FALSE          FALSE TRUE FALSE
#3           TRUE          FALSE TRUE  TRUE
#4          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE
#5          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Note that `TRUE` (logical) is different from `"TRUE"` (character). So first verify if your dataset contains logical values or character values before trying out the answers below.

---

This is your current code where you are dropping `Community.name` and calculating number of `TRUE` values in the dataset.

```
library(dplyr)

data_2 <- data_1 %>% 
      mutate(True_Count = rowSums(across(-c(Community.name), `%in%`, TRUE)))
data_2

#  Community.name Community.code col1  col2 True_Count
#1           TRUE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
#2          FALSE          FALSE TRUE FALSE          1
#3           TRUE          FALSE TRUE  TRUE          2
#4          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
#5          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
```

Seems to work as expected. We ignore `Community.Name` and calculate number of `TRUE` values in the dataset.

---

Now your question,

> I actually don't want to drop any columns from my function.

For that you can use `everything()` in `across` to include all the columns.

```
data_3 <- data_1 %>% 
           mutate(True_Count = rowSums(across(everything(), `%in%`, TRUE)))

data_3

#  Community.name Community.code col1  col2 True_Count
#1           TRUE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          3
#2          FALSE          FALSE TRUE FALSE          1
#3           TRUE          FALSE TRUE  TRUE          3
#4          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
#5          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
```

Also note that `everything()` is default in `?across`.

---

> Also, I tried to do this a much simpler way using just rowSums and no mutate

Yes, using `rowSums` with no `mutate` is much simpler way giving the same answer.

```
data_1$True_Count <- rowSums(data_1)
data_1

#  Community.name Community.code col1  col2 True_Count
#1           TRUE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          3
#2          FALSE          FALSE TRUE FALSE          1
#3           TRUE          FALSE TRUE  TRUE          3
#4          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
#5          FALSE           TRUE TRUE FALSE          2
```

---

> Lastly there was one more behavior that I did not understand. If I run the first code, more than once, the counts in the True_Count column cease to be correct.

That might be because initially you don't have `True_Count` column in the dataset. So for the first time when you run the code `True_Count` column is added in your dataset `data_1`, now when you run the code second time it also uses `True_Count` for calculation which is something you don't want.

Comment: For the rowSums script -- can you rewrite the script you provided? because after you call rowSums you give the name of the dataframe but not the variable to be counted